# How do I edit the background color of backBarButtonItem (UINavigationItem) ? iOS 4.3 issue

Tags: ios, ios4, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, backbarbuttonitem

I am trying to edit the background behind the backBarButtonItem as it insists on remaining white. I have edited the background color of the entire navigation bar but to no avail.

It only seems to affect iOS4 however, seeing as the:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

code works on iOS5. I have also tried to edit the navigation bar using this method also:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_actionbar_edit.png"];
[img drawInRect:rect];
}
@end;
```

however this code results in all of my navigation bars to change, which is something that I do not want. Is there any simple code that I could use to simply change the BG colour of a buttonItem based on the navigation bar?

Comment: Set a tag for each navigation bar and check tag for navigationBar before you set an image.Put an if condition to check the tag number of a navigation item.

Answer (score 1):

Set the tint of your navigation bar to change the color of the navigation bar button items:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect for me. I am still left with the same issue of having the Back Button remaining with a white background that I am unable to change. I believe it is due to a previous implementation of the UINavigationBar code on the AppDelegate file.

Comment: Maybe you could post some more code, with what you're doing with the navigation bar and the bar button items. I believe that you have to set the tintColor after adding the buttons to the navigation bar, if that's not what you're already doing.